# Описание и реализация класса или функции в одном .h файле или в раздельном .h и .cpp

Tags: c++

Гуглил, читал, в том числе и тут, но так и не могу понять, в чем итоговая разница для скомпилированного exe-шника, если в проекте функция или класс реализуются в одном .h файле или разделяется на описание и реализацию на .h и .cpp ?

Я понял, только, что если запихнуть все реализацию в хедер файл, то в случае большого проекта и в случае, если в проекте будет много #include "my_class.h" компилятор(или точнее транслятор ?) запихнет код моего класса в каждую "функцию", где стоит include.

Но, я так и не могу понять, на сам двоичный код готового exe-шника - это как то влияет ?
То, ну хорошо, я разделил описание функции или класса и его реализацию, ну компилятор скомпилировал - это отдельно, НО, как это далее все в exe-файле тогда учитывается ? То есть, как функция, которая ссылается на мою функцию в итоговом бинарнике будет на нее ссылается ?

Вот вопрос в том, в чем разница именно в итоговом файле ?

Comment: Итоговому экзешнику от этого даже немного лучше (потому что у компилятора больше возможностей для оптимизации, т.к. он видит тела функций, а не только их объявления). Но злоупотребление этим сильно вредит скорости компиляции.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а влияет на скорость в ран-тайме ?

Comment: Да. Посмотрите первую часть комментария еще раз.

Comment: Попробуйте оба варианта и сравните.

Comment: @user7860670, сравнить бинарники имеете ввиду ?

Comment: Именно. (7символов)

Comment: @user7860670, сравнивал. Но, как интерпретировать это сравнение не знаю. У меня получилось, что exe-шники равны по размеру и отличаются в значении только в 2ух байтах.

Comment: Я имел ввиду сравнение сгенерированного машинного кода. Откройте дизассемблер в любой приличной IDE. Если только два байта отличаются, то вот вам и ответ - почти никакой разницы.

Comment: Размещение функций в .cpp нужно, если вы рассчитываете далее использовать их в разделяемых (.so/.dll) библиотеках

Comment: @avp Размещение в .cpp для этого не нужно.

Comment: @user7860670, и из каких же объектников вы будете их собирать?

Comment: @avp Из каких угодно, однако суть в том, что размещать функции в .cpp не обязательно.

Comment: @user7860670, если вставите в библиотечные .cpp реализации из .h, то потом обязательно налетите на double definition, когда кто-то воспользуется еще раз этими же .h и будет линковаться с либой из них

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на этот вопрос несколько сложнее, чем может показаться.

С одной стороны, чтобы имплементация не шаблонной функции была в заголовке, ее необходимо сделать `inline`. Это не гарантирует, что код функции будет действительно заинлайнен, но делает это более вероятным. В случае, если оптимизатор решит заинлайнить функцию, то ее код будет "размазан" по выполняемому файлу. Это не обязательно плохо, поскольку оптимизатор решил, что так код будет работать быстрее. Если же она не была заинлайнена, то в результирующем выполняемом файле будет только одна копия - точно с тем же результатом, как если бы вы ее скомпилировали как обычную функцию.

С другой стороны, если имплементация будет в файле .cpp (или подобных), то инлайн такой функции становится менее вероятным (хотя некоторые компиляторы позволяют это делать). То есть скорее всего будет одна копия функции.

В общем, это больше влияет на время компиляции проекта и некоторые оптимизации. На размер проекта значительного влияния оказывать не должно.

Comment: я вот этого ни как не могу понять - "если оптимизатор решит заинлайнить функцию, то ее код будет "размазан" по выполняемому файлу" и "если имплементация будет в файле .cpp То есть скорее всего будет одна копия функции."(с). Я так понял это может и влияет на размер exe-шника. Но я не могу понять, если функция инлайнится в другие функции, то получается, что каждая функция, которая включает мою функцию содержит ее код, и как бы в ран-тайме выполняется инструкция за инструкцией. А, как тогда выполняется в ран-тайме код в которой - "скорее всего будет одна копия функции." ?

Comment: "А, как тогда выполняется в ран-тайме код в которой - "скорее всего будет одна копия функции." ?" как обычная функция, просто `inline` функция может встречаться много раз в разных единицах трансляции, линковщик выбросит лишнии копии. Если же не `inline` функция будет встречаться в разных единицах трансляции - это приведет к ошибке линкования.